# Please can someone help me draw this in a latex. I'm not good in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, drawing

[image: Model diagram]

Please can someone help me draw this diagram

Comment: Divide and conquer: What parts do you have? 1. The axis. 2. the horizontal lines with each three nodes. 3. The arc with 3b. three arrows pointing to it. 4. Some seemingly randomly angled lines with 4b. text at one and the angle at another.

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed here. Show some work and people can suggest enhancements. The first pages of the TikZ manual are a very good tutorial, and you'll find numerous examples that can easily be adapted to your use case.

Comment: Since the question got closed: Here's [my contribution](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tex.sx/blob/master/652638.tex) and the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jevLh.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're lucky that I'm procrastinating mood `:-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<->] (7,0)node[below right]{$x$} -- (0,0)node[left]{$z=0$} -- (0,4.5) node[left]{$z$} ;
\draw[very thick] (0,0)--++(2,0)node[below]{$v(0,t)=0$}--++(3,0)node[below]{$\theta(0,t)=0$}--++(1,0);
\draw[very thick] (0,4)node[left]{$z=d$}--++(2,0)node[above]{$v(d,t)=0$}--++(3,0)node[above]{$\theta(d,t)=0$}--++(1,0);
\draw[very thick] (2,0) to [out=40,in=-40] ++(0,4) ;
\draw[very thick] (4,1)--++(30:1) ;
\draw[dashed](4,1)--++(1,0) ;
\draw(4.8,1)arc(0:30:.8)node[midway,right]{$\theta(z,t)$} ;
\draw[very thick] (4,.3)--+(1,0)
                  (4,.6)--+(10:1)
                  (4,2.7)--+(-35:1)
                  (4,3.2)--+(-10:1)node[right]{director, $\mathbf{n}$}
                  (4,3.8)--+(1,0);
\draw[line width=3pt,arrows={-Triangle[]}] (1.5,1) --+(1,0);
\draw[line width=3pt,arrows={-Triangle[]}] (1.8,2)node[left]{$v(z,t)$} --+(1,0);
\draw[line width=3pt,arrows={-Triangle[]}] (1.5,3) --+(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Is this my first Ti*k*Z answer ever?)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a bit of a hint to get you started but its not the complete answer but it should give you a start,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) -- (10,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,8) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,6) -- (9,6);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (9,0);

    \node[left] at (0,0) (a) {$z=0$};
    \node[left] at (0,6) (b) {$z=d$};
    \node[above] at (3,6) (c) {$v(d,t)=0$};
    \node[above] at (6,6) (d) {$\theta(d,t)=0$};
    \node[below] at (3,0) (e) {$v(0,t)=0$};
    \node[below] at (6,0) (f) {$\theta0,t)=0$};

    \draw [bend right,-] (e) to (c);

    \draw [arrows = {-Stealth[scale=2]}]   (3,4)   -- (4,4);

    \draw (6,5) -- (8,4.5) node[right] {director, $n$};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

let me know if I can explain any code for you, its not neat but its a start.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: We all need help when we start using a new package, and i'm only still learning, but at least now you have something you can post so more expert people can help with.